# Safari file upload not accepting MKV video files

Tags: file-upload, safari, plupload, mkv

I have a file input element with an accept attribute which should allow various video formats. The only one I cannot select is MKV.

```
<input id="fileOne" type="file" accept="video/mp4,.mp4,video/avi,.avi,video/mpeg,.mpeg,.mpg,video/3gpp,.3gp,.divx,video/x-flv,.flv,video/x-matroska,.mkv,video/quicktime,.mov,audio/ogg,.ogg,video/webm,.webm,video/x-ms-wmv,.wmv">
```

It is set to accept the following:

```
video/mp4,.mp4,
video/avi,.avi,
video/mpeg,.mpeg,.mpg,
video/3gpp,.3gp,.divx,
video/x-flv,.flv,
video/x-matroska,.mkv,
video/quicktime,.mov,
audio/ogg,.ogg,
video/webm,.webm,
video/x-ms-wmv,.wmv
```

I cannot select MKV files in Safari when opening the file upload dialog. (The filename is greyed out). Should I be doing something different?

I have tagged PLUpload as I am generating the file upload element using PLUpload with the following filters:

```
filters: {
      mime_types: [
        { title: "Video Files", extensions: "mp4,avi,mpeg,mpg,3gp,divx,flv,mkv,mov,ogg,webm,wmv" }
      ]
    }
```